# What is the difference between Gatsby Link and React Router Link?

Tags: react-router, gatsby

I have got a website with 2 components routed by 2 different paths and *link* to each other. When I use react router Route / Link to implement these *links*, there is only 1 html page and javascript application bundle in the final build by webpack. When I use Gatsby Link instead, I see both html pages are generated, but each of the pages still behaves like Single-Page-Application (i.e. click on a link does not cause a request to the server to fetch the other page, it is just rendered dynamically).

- So, what is the difference between these 2 page link technologies?
- What is the point to use Gatsby Link if it works the same way as react-router Link?
- What are the implications of using both together on the same website? eg. router links for dynamic part of an application and Gatsby links for static pages like help pages.

Note: this is a continuation of the question [Clarification on Gatsby page load network request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46680835/clarification-on-gatsby-page-load-network-request) but relates to slightly different area.

Answer (score 6):

Gatsby Link is a required wrapper for the react-router-dom Link component. The two work the same but Gatsby's version adds prefetching as well as prevents route transitions until the next page's resources are finished loading.

Things will break in weird ways if you use React Route `<Link>`.

Comment: Thanks. I am new to this. Could you please explain what "automatic substitution" and "service worker" are? Also, why Gatsby-Link is a future proof but router link is not?

Comment: NavLink augments Link, while Gatsby-Link leverages both. A service worker is a script that the browser executes in the background even if the webpage is not loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation states:

gatsby-link is a wrapper for the  component in react-router. It automatically prefixes urls and handles prefetching.

gatsby-link auto-detects whether to use a plain  or  based on what props you pass it.